# Algorithm - Find point with minimum distance travelled

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, distance, axis

This algorithm is to find the best point to meet, such that the distance travelled by all people is minimum.

To elaborate -

Consider the below line, an x-axis with each person in different point to the 0th position(imagine x-y axis). Each point denotes the distance he is from 0th position.

```
                                  |
---30-------15-----10--------5----0----6-----------20-----------40-----50--
                                  |
```

Now Find come up with an algorithm to find the point where each person has to travel and get together such that the total distance travelled is minimum.

Note - I thought of finding median/average, does not work always.
How about choosing nearest point to 0th position? Again not always.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Can you give an example where finding average does not work?

Comment: @ShubhamBhattar - Take above example itself. average => 186/8 = 23.25. Now with this 23.25, which point are you going to choose firstly?

Comment: Shouldn't it be (6+20+40+50-5-10-15-30)/8 = 7 since people are on the both sides of x-axis?

Comment: @ShubhamBhattar - That's a point. Have you tried with different scenarios and verified if average is the solution? If not, could you try your formula and let me know.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median.  Geometric median is what you are looking for.  Of course you would only need a 2d version implemented.

Comment: Why do we need to *"imagine x-y axis"*? Are there points that are not on the X-axis?

Comment: @trincot - Ohk, Dont imagine if you can make sense of the above diagram

Comment: If this is a 1-d problem, then the median point always works.  If you have an even number of points then any point between the middle two will do. If this is a 2d problem (your language makes it hard to tell which), then you want the geometric median, as user2253572 says.

Comment: Is it a 1D or 2D problem? It is not clear from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all positions are in one dimension (i.e. along one axis only), optimal solution is **median** of all positions.

*The median is defined such that half the values are larger than, and half are smaller than, the median. If elements in the sample data increase arithmetically, when placed in some order, then the median and arithmetic average are equal. For example, consider the data sample {1,2,3,4}. The average is 2.5, as is the median. However, when we consider a sample that cannot be arranged so as to increase arithmetically, such as {1,2,4,8,16}}, the median and arithmetic average can differ significantly. In this case, the arithmetic average is 6.2 and the median is 4. In general, the average value can vary significantly from most values in the sample, and can be larger or smaller than most of them.*
Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean

In above example,

- total distance with **average** value (6.2) as solution = **23.2**
- total distance with **median** value (4) as solution = **21**, which of course is the lower distance, hence optimal solution